# writing images to .odf/.odt with QtTextDocumentWriter giving realy low quality output

Tags: c++, qt

I'm handling some charts in my Qt application and need to output them to a .odf/.odt file. Found on Qt documentation about this [method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocumentwriter.html#write).

I've implemented it by getting a QPixmap from the chart and then converting it to a Qimage that is written to the QTextDocument.
When i open the output document my charts are realy blurry, seems like a bad compression or something is happening.

What did i get wrong about handling .odf?

If i try to use the same QTextDocument to write to a .pdf or in a QTextEdit seems to work fine. But realy need to get the final output to a .odf file so that's no good for me. *Actualy also a docx or similar could be fine*

```
//create a chart and return it as an image
QImage getChartImage(foo) {
    //stuff that handles creating a (QChart *chart) from given foo data

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    chartView->resize(1000,750);

    QPixmap chartImage = chartView->grab();
    chartImage.save("test.png", "PNG");    //just for testing, here looks fine
    return chartImage.toImage();
}
```

and then in my main

```
//in main
Qimage chartImage = getChartImage(foo);

//setting up document
QTextEdit *editor = new QTextEdit;    //not needed, but this works too
// if no editor should be: 
//QTextDocument *document = new QTextDocument;
QTextDocument *document = new QTextDocument(editor);
QTextCursor cursor(document);

//adding image to document
document->addResource(QTextDocument::ImageResource, QUrl("my_img.png"), chartImage);
QTextImageFormat imageFormat;
imageFormat.setName("img1.png");
cursor.insertImage(imageFormat);
cursor.insertBlock();
cursor.insertText("some random text!");

//show on editor; not needed but works
editor->setDocument(document);
editor->setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("I should work fine!"));
editor->resize(1000, 750);
editor->show();

//and here the bad output happens
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(nullptr,QObject::tr("Save File"),"output_file.odf",QObject::tr("Open Document ('''.odf)"));
QTextDocumentWriter fileWriter (fileName);
fileWriter.setFormat("odf");
fileWriter.write(document);
```

Here you can see how the charts get's saved to the document and how it should actualy look like.

blurry output on .odf

[image]

output on QTextEdit

[image]

saving the QPixmap as .png

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this? Or maybe an other method that I can use?

Comment: What is the result with [`imageFormat.setQuality(100);`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextimageformat.html#setQuality) ?

Comment: that solved it, thanks!